# Left vertical Tab In jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am new to jqm and i was going through their documentation..I can see there is only horizontal tab .Please see this http://jsfiddle.net/7wp57/ . Is there any vertical tabs in jqm ?

I tried something like , But i am not really good at CSS , some one please guide me.

```
.ui-footer-fixed {
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    float: left;
}
```

I need something like below

[image]

Comment: which version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navbar buttons are converted into *grid* layout depending on number of buttons.

For example, three buttons are wrapped in div `.ui-grid-b` and each one is wrapped in `li` with class `.ui-block-a`, `-b` & `-c`. Each block has width set to 33%, all you need is to override block's width and set it to 100%.

```
.ui-navbar [class^="ui-block"] {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/w4uxg/)**

Comment: +1 for explanation, but that dont look like tab ? i meant something like http://imgur.com/17ipy7D

Comment: @Vishnu hi, maybe i misunderstood you. You want a vertical/side navbar?

Comment: yea bro  i need left vertical navbar

Comment: @vishnu why don't use panel?

Comment: panel covers 80% of space .. and i already have panel for menu..so it will mess up..can you come to private chat ?

Comment: @vishnu you can create a custom panel with nested inner panels. I don't have access to pc right now.

Comment: Check your email. @vishnu